# WPF: File not found

Tags: c#, json, wpf

I am using this class to return the content of a Json file, but i am having trouble finding the json file. I might be missing something very obvious, but I am currently clueless as to what it may be.

I would really appreciate it if one of you hardcore programmers could look over the code and pictures below. (I can't use images in my posts yet sorry!)

Image with error and solution explorer:

[image]

```
namespace MVVM.Model
{
    class JsonHandler
    {
        private JsonArray _placeHolder;
        public JsonArray PlaceHolder
        {
            get { return _placeHolder; }
            set { _placeHolder = value; }
        }
        public JsonHandler()
        {
            extractJson();
        }

        private async void extractJson()
        {
            Uri dataUri = new Uri("ms-appx:///Model/SampleData.json");
            StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(dataUri);
            // Json
            string jsonText = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
            JsonObject jsonObject = JsonObject.Parse(jsonText);
            JsonArray jsonArray = jsonObject["Restaurent"].GetArray();

            this.PlaceHolder = jsonArray;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you double-checked the path and that the file exists where you tell the program it is?

Comment: Yes. I have tried a lot of different path's. e.g. MVVM/Model/SampleData.json

Comment: It might be relative - what about `ms-appx:///SampleData.json` since it's in the same file as the code that's calling it?

Comment: I tried that as well Tim. Without any luck unfortunately
Edit: I'll look it over Cory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Properties for `SampleData.json`, make sure you have set *Build Action* to "Content" and *Copy to Output Directory* to "Copy Always".

Comment: Hi Cory.
The Build Action, does not have the value Output, but i've set the Copy to Output Directory to Copy Always. It didn't have any effect yet though.

Comment: Oops, I meant "Content". After you build your project, check the "bin" directory for a "Model" folder with "SampleData.json". If that's missing, you have the reason for your `FileNotFoundException`. These settings will produce a file in that location when you build.

Comment: Content made it work! 
Thanks a lot for the explanation and the help. I'll accept your answer in 2 minuts (when it allows me to)